# Не делать окно активным при вызове pyplot.show

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Когда я перерисовываю картинку в цикле:

```
pyplot.pause(0.1)
```

или

```
pyplot.show(block=False)
```

или

```
pyplot.draw()
```

управление передаётся в это окно, и если я работаю в другой программе,
поверх неё постоянно всплывает окно с перерисованным графиком.

Какой параметр надо поставить, чтобы окно не становилось активным, а график перерисовывался?